# ¿Cómo ordenar un vector sin sort() en Java?

Tags: java, array

Dados dos vectores A[n] y  B[m], en forma desordenada haga lo siguiente:

1. Usar la funcion sort de java, para ordenarlos.
2. Imprima los vectores A y B para verlos ordenados
3. Combínelos en un tercer vector sin usar la función sort en el vector C, pero que el vector C, quede ordenado. Tiene que ir leyendo el elemento (i) del Vector A, y el elemento (j) del Vector B y los va intercalando en el vector C. Si hay elemento repetidos, insértelos también.
4. Imprima el vector C.

Esto es lo que llevo pero no me intercala los vectores y me bota solo 5 valores

```
package System.out;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class vectores_desordenados {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         int[] n = {9, 4, 5, 1, 3};
         int[] m = {4, 2, 1, 5, 9};
         int[] c = {4, 1, 3, 9, 0};
         int i;
         Arrays.sort(n);
         Arrays.sort(m);
         
         for (int A : n)
             System.out.print(A);
    
         System.out.println("\n");
         
         for (int B : m)
         System.out.print(B);
         
    for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        c[i] = n[i];
        c[i] = m[i];
    }
    System.out.println();
    
    System.out.print("array C: ");
    for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(c[i] + " ");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La ordenación está correcta, pero esto:

```
for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    c[i] = n[i];
    c[i] = m[i];
}
```

lo único que está haciendo es hacer que C sea igual que M, ya que para cada iteración siempre pones el valor de M al final (`c[i] = m[i];`)

Lo que necesitas es hacer una comparación y quedarte con el valor mayor:

```
for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    if(n[i] > m[i]){
        c[i] = n[i];
    }else{
        c[i] = m[i];
    }
}
```

Con esto el resultado será `array C: 1 3 4 5 9`  en vez de `array C: 1 2 4 5 9` 
En cuanto a que el array C solo tenga 5 valores... tú lo inicializaste con 5 valores aquí: `int[] c = {4, 1, 3, 9, 0};`  así que no puede tener más de 5.

Si quieres generar un array con los 10 valores ordenados, necesitarás hacer algo así:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    int[] n = {9, 4, 5, 1, 3};
    int[] m = {4, 2, 1, 5, 9};
    int[] c = new int[10];
    int i;
    Arrays.sort(n);
    Arrays.sort(m);
     
    for (int A : n)
        System.out.print(A);

    System.out.println("\n");
     
    for (int B : m)
    System.out.print(B);
    //Añado la variable j para recorrer el segundo array
    int j = 0;
    //La j se incrementa de 2 en 2 ya que necesitamos recorrer el doble de valores
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < n.length; i++, j+=2) {
        if(n[i] < m[i]){
            c[j] = n[i];
            c[j+1] = m[i];
        }else{
            c[j] = m[i];
            c[j+1] = n[i];
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println();
    
    System.out.print("array C: ");
    for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(c[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Edito de nuevo: Ordenar un array sin .sort()

```
int[] c = {4, 1, 3, 9, 0};
for (int i = 0; i < c.length-1; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < c.length-i-1; j++){
        if (c[j] > c[j+1]){
            int temp = c[j]; 
            c[j] = c[j+1]; 
            c[j+1] = temp; 
        }
    }
}
```

A esta manera de ordenar un array se le conoce como Bubble-sort, basicamente comparas parejas de valores y mueves el mayor a un lado siempre. De este modo el mayor siempre acabará hacia la derecha de todo.

Comment: hola bro, muchas gracias por tu respuesta pero al punto le falta algo, creo que no me expliqué bien, primero los vectores N y M deben quedar ordenados por el método sort, luego el vector C debe quedar ordenado pero sin usar sort y por último los vectores N y M deben quedar intercalados en el vector c, si me hice entender?, espero tu respuesta

Comment: Es imposible que un vector de tamaño 5 como es el C que declaras tenga 10 valores (los 5 de N y los 5 de M), ya su tamaño siempre estará limitado a 5

Comment: listo bro, estaba pensando era en ordenar el vector C sin la funcion sort, e intercalar los 3 vectores en un cuarto vector, supongo que si se podría

Comment: Cito tu enunciado: "Tiene que ir leyendo el elemento (i) del Vector A, y el elmento (j) del Vector B y los va intercalando en el vector C." esto implica que C debe tener tamaño 10. Si decides utilizar un cuarto vector, el código es el mismo que puse en la respuesta pero cambiando el nombre del vector

Comment: bro y como puedo ordenar el vector c pero sin usar sort?

Comment: He vuelto a editar la respuesta para añadir un ejemplo de cómo ordenar el vector sin usar .sort(). Espero que te sirva

Comment: @Gabitohh no entiendo tu pregunta. Todo lo que puse en mi respuesta funciona sin tener en cuenta la longitud del array

Comment: Cierto, no leí bien.

Comment: @Benito-B gracias bro por tu ayuda, una ultima duda, no sabes como ordenar los vectores A y B en el C pero sin ningún tipo de sort?, agradezco tu respuesta

Comment: Si c tiene tamaño 5 y tanto A como B tienen tamaño 5, es imposible que cojan, porque tendrás 10 números diferentes y C solo acepta 5. Si C tiene tamaño 10, en la respuesta está cómo montarlo ordenado.

Comment: si pero es que mi tutor me dijo que no se podía con burbuja, que era sin nada de sort, me refiero a organizar el vector A y el B en el c = [10] sin ningun tipo de sort

Comment: @perez El código que te puse arriba hace justamente eso, ordena los arrays que indicaste en un array C[10]. Es el código grande, el que está justo después de "Si quieres generar un array con los 10 valores ordenados, necesitarás hacer algo así:". Y los ordena sin usar ningún algoritmo de ordenación, simplemente coge los datos de los otros y los va metiendo por orden